# Differents subclass instances with same superclass instance data

Tags: c++11, inheritance, openmp

I'm working with OpenMp and I need to copy an instance of a class N times (one for each thread). I'm using inheritance to create my struct of data. For example:

```
// Super class
class vehicle {
    private:
        // general attributes of any vehicle
        .......
}

// Sub class
class car : public vehicle {
    private:
        // some specific attributes of a car
        string color;
        ......
    public:
        car(string color);
        car(car _car);
        void change_color(string color);
}
```

If I have 4 threads, I need to have 4 instance of the car but I would like that this 4 instances shares the same specific data of the super class (only one copy in memory). For example, if I have the follow code:

```
int main() {
    .....
    string colors[] = {"green", "blue", "red", "orange"};
    .....
    car base_car = new car(colors[0]); 
    car cars[4];
    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
        cars[i] = new car(base_car);
    }
    ....
    int thread_id;
    #pragma omp parallel private (thread_id)
        thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();
        car thread_car = cars[thread_id];
        thread_car.change_color(colors[thread_id]);          
}
```

I'd like that the instances of the car in the cars array share the attributes of the super class vehicle, that is to say, I would like to have only one copy of the data (in memory) of the attributes of the super class vheicle and 4 copy of the data of the derived class car.

This is possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Move object _state_ (attributes, in your case) to a separate object `car_properties`. Use a `shared_ptr` (for example) to share those object between different instances. You'd also better to make it immutable.

Comment: This is possible, but not the way you are picturing it ("automagically" via inheritance). You would have to create, and reference, the shared state yourself, in the constructors and assignment operators of `class car`. And unless you have a **good** reason to believe that just giving each `car` its own copy of that state *will* be a significant problem in a "production grade" application, I would advise against such a "shared state" scheme. For "toying around" with "car" and "vehicle", it would definitely be overly complex and error prone.

Comment: Yes, I have a good reason to do this. I have a problem of memory. I have an object that the 90% of data are static and only the other 10% of data is modified by the threads. Until now I did a copy of the object N times (once for each thread), but the problem is when I execute the softwere in a cluster with 16-32 threads, because the object use a significant quantite of memory.

Comment: For exemple, I have one case that the object use 8% of the memory and if I use 16 threads I have 8*16 = 128% of memory and the SO kills the process. I had thought with this solution, but my idea was to do this with some technique using inheritance... Well, if its not mossible I will do it with some other way. Thank you!

Comment: Go fo "has_a" (composition) instead of "is_a" (inheritance). Create a different class for holding the static data, and have the class with the dynamic data hold a shared_ptr to an instance of the static data class. Not everything has to be, or should be handled as, inheritance. With two separate classes and composition, you can keep things *much* simpler.

Comment: Yes, finally I used composition and now works fine. Some times I've tendency to use too much inheritance and I don't think with other solutions. Thank you!